# SmtpClient exception causes WebApi via Owin to never return

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing a really odd problem that I hope someone will have a solution for. I've created an ASP.NET web application with Owin and WebApi via Owin.

I've created a Git repo that shows the issue: https://github.com/robbaman/smtp-error-example

#### Code

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

**TestController.cs**

```
public class TestController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet, Route("test")]
    public void Test() {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("test@example.com");
            message.Body = "haha";
            message.Subject = "ohhh";
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("testasync")]
    public async Task TestAsync() {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("test@example.com");
            message.Body = "haha";
            message.Subject = "ohhh";
            await client.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("test2")]
    public async Task Test2() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### Nuget Packages used

- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin

#### Web.config Smtp Section

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="support@example.com">
            <network host="mailserver" enableSsl="true" userName="support@example.com" 
                     port="587" password="password" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

#### Symptoms

When using the configuration above (or check the GitHub repo) and running the application, there are some strange things happening:

When navigating to `/test`, you get the expected exception that the `mailserver` hostname is invalid. When navigating to `/test2` you get the expected `NotImplementedException`.

When navigating to `/testasync` however, the same hostname exception occurs, but no response is ever sent to the browser. It will just keep loading and loading... I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What you need is HttpResponse. You might have to call TestAsync() function using another function and fetch the result of the Task. Once you get the result of the Task, you can convert it to an HttpResponse object as per your requirement.

Comment: In your `mailSettings` of web.config please add correct smtp server information and for `/test2`. Look on the function of `Test2`, you are throwing exception there. (`throw new NotImplementedException();`)

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `TestAsync()` like this-

```
[HttpGet, Route("testasync")]
public string CallTestAsync()
{
    Task t = TestAsync();
    string response = "";

    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        response = t.Exception.InnerException.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        response = "Success";
    }
    return response;
}
```

Remove the attribute- `[HttpGet, Route("testasync")]` from `TestAsync()`